# Template Clase Abstractas C++

Tags: c++

Hola tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo muchas funciones que realizan distintas operaciones, por lo tanto quise agrupar este compartamiento con una interface(clase abstracta) del tipo *Evaluable*

Ahora como cada función devuelve algo distinto pensé colocar algo del estilo.

```
+evaluar():void*
```

Pero no me parece lo más lindo, entonces implementé lo siguiente:

Evaluable.h

```
template <class T>
class Evaluable{
public:
    Evaluable();
    virtual ~Evaluable();
    virtual T evaluar()=0;
};
```

Evaluable.c

```
    template <typename T>
Evaluable<T>::Evaluable(){}
```

Por lo tanto una clase derivada sería algo de este estilo.
Numb.h

```
class Number:public Evaluable<int>{
int numero;
public:
    Number(std::string cadena);
    ~Number();
    int evaluar();
};
```

Pero me tira error:

```
Number.cpp:6: referencia a `Evaluable<int>::Evaluable()' sin definir
Number.cpp:15: referencia a `Evaluable<int>::~Evaluable()' sin definir
```

Lo que quiero es tener la posibilidad de que tener una listas de *Evaluables* y llamar a cada uno con *evaluar()*

Comment: Asi como pusiste tu código es dificil saber cual es la linea 6 y la 15. Tambien por las caracteristicas que comentaste sobre tu programa tal vez te convenga revisar como se implementa el patron de diseño command y tal vez ya no necesites los templates:
http://www.bogotobogo.com/DesignPatterns/command.php

Comment: Perdón. El error me tirá en las lineas donde está el constructor y destructor de Number, lo que me imagino es que en algún momento invoca al constructor/destructor de Evaluable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El compilador básicamente te está diciendo que no encuentra ni la implementación del constructor ni la del destructor del template. Si no deseas hacer nada en dichas funciones puedes hacer lo siguiente en C++98:

```
template <class T>
class Evaluable{
public:
    Evaluable() {}
    virtual ~Evaluable() {}
    virtual T evaluar()=0;
};
```

O, en C++11 y posteriores:

```
template <class T>
class Evaluable{
public:
    Evaluable() = default;
    virtual ~Evaluable() = default;
    virtual T evaluar()=0;
};
```

Aun así esto que te he explicado únicamente sería necesario si la clase fuese heredable... que no va a ser el caso. Una limitación de los `templates` en C++ es que no pueden tener miembros abstractos (o virtuales puros, como prefieras). En cambio sí que admiten miembros virtuales. Esto quiere decir que tu solución de "evaluar" no va a funcionar.

La solución que puedes emplear es especializar el `template` para que haga lo que tu deseas. En este caso no hace falta que la función sea `virtual`:

```
template <class T>
class Evaluable{
public:
    T evaluar() { return T(); } // Implementación por defecto
};

template <>
class Evaluable<int>{
public:
    int evaluar()
    { /* implementación específica */ }
};
```

La pega que tiene esta solución es que las diferentes especializaciones del `template` no van a tener una herencia común. Van a ser clases independientes. Eso sí, si tenemos en cuenta que para que una serie de clases hereden de una interfaz común han de tener al menos un método con exactamente la misma firma y que en tu caso eso no va a ser posible porque *evaluar* va a tener diferentes valores de retorno parece evidente que esto no va a ser un problema.